# Hide/Remove header from dashboard component

Tags: dashboard

[image]

Is it possible to hide the header of the standard dashboard component inserted in a home page?

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be apreciated.

Samuel Anjos

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly remove or hide the header from a standard dashboard component using point-and-click configuration options. However, you can achieve this through customization using the Salesforce Lightning Component Framework.

Below is just the example code for customization of the same:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <!-- Include your CSS for hiding the header -->
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.dashboardWrapperCSS}" />

    <!-- Include your dashboard component here -->
    <iframe src="/lightning/r/Dashboard/[Dashboard_Id]/view" width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0" />
</aura:component>
```

```
/* dashboardWrapperCSS.css */
/* Hide the dashboard component header */
.slds-page-header {
    display: none !important;
}
```